# Migrate from Azure SQL back to Access

Tags: sql, azure, ms-access

I have a SQL database in Azure. Is there any way of downloading the SQL database in .mdb format?

Comment: Creating a script would be a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way of downloading the SQL database in .mdb format?

Not directly in .mdb format but what you can do is export the database in `BACPAC` format and save this file in Blob Storage. Once the file is there, you can download this file. You can find more information about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export. If you're doing this from Azure Portal, please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export-portal

Next step would be to create a local database using this BACPAC file. Please see this link on instructions on how to import a BACPAC File to create a new user database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh710052.aspx.

Last step would be to export this database and import it in Access. You can make use of SQL Server Import/Export Wizard to do so. Please see this link for more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx.